# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error show when axios get call

Tags: reactjs, ajax, react-redux, axios, frontend

Axios fetch error. when I try to get data from API, with params

```
const CategoryURL = 'https://vuestore.doyenhub.com/api/catalog/vue_storefront_catalog/category/_search'
const FetchCategory = async() => {
    await axios.get(CategoryURL, {
        params: {
            from: 0,
            size: 5,
            sort: ""
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('data Fetched')
    })
    .catch(err => 
        console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: This domain `https://vuestore.doyenhub.com` is not allow you to request from different domain like `localhost`

Comment: but when i hit this url from postman and browser it show me data.  https://vuestore.doyenhub.com/api/catalog/vue_storefront_catalog/category/_search?from=0&size=5&sort=

Comment: XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. Read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: postman and browser access is different story . research more about `CORS`